# Background colour in Mailchimp

Tags: mailchimp

I have chosen the 'full width' template for mail chimp and I cannot for the life of me change the background colour of each row.

It allows a full width strip of colour for the header, but not for the blocks that follow. I can put inline styles or embedded css in there, but I do not know how to target each row.

I have been sent emails that feature this but I cannot achieve this. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that background colour can be changed for "boxed text" content sections, but not in other content sections. Even within boxed text, padding is automatically added, so the background colour won't cover the full width (unless you edit the source code.)

***If you want all the rows to have the same background***, you can change it by clicking on "design" at the top of the right hand menu. Within that section you can set a background for each page section (header, body, footer.)

***If you want the rows/content sections within each page section to different colours*** you'll need to edit the source code directly.

You can do this from within mail chimp by clicking edit for the section you want to change the background for, and then clicking on the source <> icon. If you want to edit it outside of mail chimp, you can export the html by going to your "templates", and on the right hand side there will be an "edit" and a dropdown arrow button. You can export the html by clicking the dropdown.

***To edit the html directly,*** add the style inline.
style="background-color: [color]; padding: 0;"